# Flot stacked bar graph, total values not adding up

Tags: jquery, flot

There are multiple columns in my graph where the total numbers don't add up. I'm not sure why. Thes are the columns with x-axis labels 1-3 and 8-10 and >500.

https://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/xtu7fvm2/6/

```
var datasets = [{"label":"Andrew Jelley","data":[[0,7],[1,22],[7,41],[4,22],[8,58],[5,74],[2,25],[6,69],[3,19],[9,17]]},{"label":"Charles Bugge","data":[[0,4],[1,6],[7,3],[4,3],[8,6],[5,2],[2,5],[6,2],[9,4],[3,0]]},{"label":"Eduardo Augusto","data":[[0,25],[1,58],[7,35],[4,145],[8,22],[5,137],[2,54],[6,69],[3,33],[9,3]]},{"label":"Frederic Sundin","data":[[0,0],[7,11],[4,9],[8,19],[5,1],[2,1],[6,8],[3,1],[9,77],[1,0]]},{"label":"James Hope","data":[[0,4],[1,21],[7,170],[4,147],[8,151],[5,94],[2,52],[6,127],[3,22],[9,16]]},{"label":"Ker Anderson","data":[[0,3],[1,1],[7,62],[4,11],[8,93],[5,43],[2,8],[6,36],[3,3],[9,29]]},{"label":"Lee Bradbury","data":[[0,3],[1,5],[7,13],[4,33],[8,12],[5,11],[2,2],[6,14],[9,7],[3,0]]},{"label":"Leonor Barros","data":[[0,55],[1,81],[7,124],[4,187],[8,56],[5,148],[2,83],[6,180],[3,39],[9,1]]},{"label":"Malcolm King","data":[[0,9],[1,17],[7,68],[4,54],[8,50],[5,63],[2,37],[6,42],[3,13],[9,49]]},{"label":"Tom Hearn","data":[[0,0],[7,9],[4,9],[8,29],[5,14],[2,5],[6,14],[9,14],[1,0],[3,0]]}];

var options = {"series":{"stack":0,"lines":{"show":false,"fill":true,"steps":false},"bars":{"show":true,"fill":1,"align":"center","barWidth":0.5,"lineWidth":0,"numbers":{}}},"xaxis":{"ticks":[[0,"0"],[1,"1-3"],[2,"4-7"],[3,"8-10"],[4,"11-24"],[5,"25-49"],[6,"50-99"],[7,"100-199"],[8,"200-500"],[9,">500"]]},"yaxis":{"min":0,"tickDecimals":0,"minTickSize":10},"grid":{"clickable":true,"hoverable":true},"legend":{"noColumns":6,"container":{"0":{},"length":1,"context":{"location":{"hash":"","search":"","pathname":"/ranops/command-centre/graphs.php","port":"","hostname":"10.97.18.39","host":"10.97.18.39","protocol":"http:","origin":"http://10.97.18.39","href":"http://10.97.18.39/ranops/command-centre/graphs.php","ancestorOrigins":{}},"jQuery111308949944251196493":1},"selector":"#manager_accountability_ageing_profile-legend"}}};
var plotArr = {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `getTotalForIndex(...)` works by summing values for one index in the dataseries, but your data series are not ordered the same, so values from different data series are summed up.

After sorting all data series (with leads to same x values having the same index), the total calculation works (see this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtu7fvm2/7/)).

Comment: does this mean the data in the datasets needs to be in order?

Comment: Yes (or the function could be changed, but that may be more work).